Block TODOs following 'Waiting' from the agenda
I often have TODOs which are not ready to do because I am waiting on input information: I have a TODO keyword called WAITING as a reminder of what exactly I'm waiting for.
Example:
*** PROJECT Report finalised
**** WAITING updated drawings from client
**** TODO Smarten up figures
**** TODO Read over once more

I have an agenda that lists all TODOs (that are actually "TODO") and what I would like is that and TODOs which come after a WAITING do not appear on the agenda.
I make this work I am happy to simply delete the WAITING entry once I have received the drawings, in this case. Or to change the layout of these entries to fit in with a simple solution.
My workaround at the moment is to put no keyword on the last two lines, but it makes work for me then to add them back in.
UPDATE:
In my set up, ORDERED doesn't seem to do anything until org-enforce-todo-dependencies is set to t. Once set, all dependent TODO are greyed out in the agenda, which is a good start.
If I could either omit these dependent entries, or (maybe better) if there was a way to sort them to the bottom of the list, I would be very interested to know how.
SOLUTION:
Set org-agenda-dim-blocked-tasks to invsible.
Bingo.
Credit due here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37649140/org-mode-how-to-show-blocked-tasks-in-custom-agenda-overriding-global-settings

See TODO dependencies in the manual and check out org-depend (available in the org-contrib package) and org-edna (available in its own package).

Maybe also work with priorities. For example set all those ToDo's Priority to [#Z] and exclude Tasks that have [#Z] priority in your agenda view

Use the ORDERED property as per manual and set:
(setq org-enforce-todo-dependencies t)
(setq org-agenda-dim-blocked-tasks 'invisible)

